# Lorentz's derivation of Lorentz force in 1892

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, maxwell-equations, specific-reference, magnetohydrodynamics

I've found Lorentz's 1892 paper 'La théorie electromagnétique de Maxwell et son application aux corps mouvants' on Wikipedia
(It's in French and I failed to find the English version.)

https://ilorentz.org/IL-publications/sources/Lorentz_AN_1892.pdf

However, I don't quite understand his derivation.Can someone help？

(The formulas for the Lorentz force are on page 443)

Comment: Why do you want Lorentz's derivation, instead of a modern treatment?

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/444936/59023